# Найти элементы нумерованного списка в ячейке таблицы Word для языка c#

Tags: c#, office-interop

Мне нужно получить список из ячейки Word, разделителем в котором являются элементы нумерованного списка. К примеру ячейка Word имеет вид:

1. Согласно чертежам проекта марка стали С255, а в ведомости поставки С345, просим уточнить.
2. В перекрытии просим предусмотреть монтажные проемы....
3. Еще какой то пункт.....

Пункты в ячейке пронумерованы инструментом "Нумерованный список"
Метод для чтения файла Word с последующим получением строк из ячейки:

```
public static string  WordCellsExtractor(Word._Application objWordApp, string targtFile){
        //Tuple<object, string, string, IList<string>>
        Char separator = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator[0];

        Word._Document objDoc = objWordApp.Documents.Open(targtFile);

        string originDate = objDoc.Tables[1].Cell(3, 4).Range.Text;
```

//
TabChersRemover - это удаление символов форматирования и всякого мусора

```
        originDate = StringFormators.TabCharsRemover(originDate);
        int tablesCount = objDoc.Tables.Count;
        string tQBodyText = objDoc.Tables[tablesCount].Cell(2, 1).Range.Text.......;}
```

Но проблема в том, что вот таким образом считав ячейку, ничего кроме знаков табуляции и непосредственно самого текста в нее не попадает. По справке я посмотрел, что за этот тип "данных" (или как это правильно назвать, объект) отвечает ListGalleries. Но толком не смог понять как считать номера или как то вообще определить их присутствие в ячейке. Как задавать нумерованные списки информация есть, а как получить номер пункта в строке не пойму и можно ли вообще?

Если получить их очень сложно, то можно ли вообще получить как то список по типу (не привязываясь к типизации переменной tqBodyList) :

tqBodyList = {"Согласно чертежам проекта марка стали С255, в ведомости поставки С345, просим уточнить", "В перекрытии просим предусмотреть монтажные проемы....", "Еще какой то пункт....."}

При условии, что один вопрос может занимаеть более 2х строк к примеру(т.е. символ новой строки уже не разделитель) и в вопросе может встречаться например шифр проекта 1.2.34 или может фигурировать надпись вроде - "пункт 1.1" или ( в конце предложения) "см. л. 1." или какого то рода иная, которую через Regex не всегда можно поймать и наверное даже не стоит пытаться, т.к. вариантов формулировки вопросов миллион и если случайно Regex не распознает конец или начало вопроса, то реестр с вопросами можно запороть так, что потом будет весело))).

Comment: мне казалось, что там есть возможность вызова .XML вместо .Text. Возможно xml будет легче парсить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как правильно заметил `morphey83` придется воспользоваться парсингом XML.
Создадим такой класс с расширяющим методом для ячейки таблицы

```
public static class WordCellExtensions
{
    public static List<string> ParseXml(this Cell cell)
    {
        //извлекаем xml ячейки
        var xml = cell.Range.XML;

        XNamespace w = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml";
        XNamespace wx = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint";
        XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);

        //находим параграфы в ячейке
        var pars = root.Element(w + "body")
                       .Element(wx + "sect")
                       .Element(w + "tbl")
                       .Element(w + "tr")
                       .Element(w + "tc")
                       .Elements(w + "p");

        //проходим по параграфам и извлекаем данные
        XName listPrName = XName.Get("listPr", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml");
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var par in pars)
        {
            //текстовое содержимое параграфа
            var text = par.Element(w + "r").Element(w + "t").Value;

            //пытаемся найти ноду связанную с форматированием списка
            var listPr = par.Element(w + "pPr")
                            .Elements()
                            .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == listPrName);
            //если такой ноды нет
            //значит это не список
            if (listPr == null)
            {
                result.Add(text);
                continue;
            }

            //получаем символ связанный со строкой в списке
            var index = listPr.Element(wx + "t").Attribute(wx + "val").Value;
            result.Add($"{index} {text}");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Тогда работать с таблицей мы можем так

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    var pathToFile = Path.Combine(dir, "TableDoc.docx");

    Application word = new Application();
    object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
    object path = pathToFile;
    object readOnly = true;
    Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss,
            ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss,
            ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

    //выбираем таблицу
    Table tb = docs.Tables[1];

    List<string> tableStrings = new List<string>();
    for (int row = 1; row <= tb.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 1; column <= tb.Columns.Count; column++)
        {
            var cell = tb.Cell(row, column);
            //используем наш расш.метод для получения данных из ячейки
            List<string> cellStrings = cell.ParseXml();
            tableStrings.AddRange(cellStrings);
        }
    }

    docs.Close();
    word.Quit();

    //вывод прочитанных данных
    tableStrings.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

На таком документе
[image: пример документа Word]
мы будем иметь такой результат
[image: пример результата чтения таблицы из документа Word]

Весь пример найти можно [здесь](https://github.com/bulsond/SOrusExamples/tree/master/WordDocReader).

**P.S. На многоуровневых списках я работу не проверял.**

Comment: Просто супер!!!! Спасибо огромное ребята.